# Avoid ControlTemplate style inheritance

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, tabcontrol, controltemplate

We use the method described in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155211/Building-a-control-template-style-for-the-tabContr) to style a "main-menu-like" TabControl. Unfortunately, the `style` part of the template is also applied to any other TabControl inside a TabItem. We'd like to try to avoid the explicit style defaulting for every child TabControl. I wish there was something like:

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl" Template="{StaticResource OfficeTabControl, inheritStyleToChildElements=false}">
```

(please note the **inheritStyleToChildElements=false**)

How to prevent the styling of other TabControls inside the main TabControl?

Any help and tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't gone through the article, but i could suggest two things:

1. Can't you give the style a name and reference it only where you want by its name
2. you want office like tab control, as far as i know office 2010 doesn't have a tab control, it has a Ribbon, and for that you can use the [Fluent Ribbon library](http://fluent.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex

Comment: 1: Thank you Sniffer. I added an x:Key to the TabItem style, moved it to top level in the ResourceDictionary and referenced it in the non-dynamic main menu TabItems. As expected, other TabItems are not affected.

2: The TabControl can be seen in Outlook 2010's "File" menu for example. The Ribbon library you mentioned seems to be quite nice, too. Will keep that in mind for next projects.

Thanks again!